# How to separate the deleted facebook apprequest messages?

Tags: facebook, apprequests, facebook-app-requests, facebook-messages

We use Apprequest (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/send-requests-using-ios-sdk/) to send gifts in a mobile application.
If the Facebook app is installed on the device then sending, receiving and managing messages are correct.
If there is no FB app on the device, the list of requests can be obtained via the Graph-api request like 
*me / apprequests? App_id =  & access_token = *.
However, there is no difference between the new messages and messages that were removed earlier, the response contains a list of all previously submitted requests. Is there any possibility how to separate the deleted messages?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
All working correct.
We received a message not removed during testing. After their removal, the list of requests kept up to date.